# Python Pandas -- why does the `in` operator work with indices and not with the data?

Tags: python, pandas

I discovered the hard way that Pandas `in` operator, applied to `Series` operates on indices and not on the actual data:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: x = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])

In [3]: x.index = [10, 20, 30]

In [4]: x
Out[4]:
10    1
20    2
30    3
dtype: int64

In [5]: 1 in x
Out[5]: False


In [6]: 10 in x
Out[6]: True
```

My intuition is that `x` series contains the number 1 and not the index 10, which is apparently wrong. What is the reason behind this behavior? Are the following approaches the best possible alternatives?

```
In [7]: 1 in set(x)
Out[7]: True

In [8]: 1 in list(x)
Out[8]: True

In [9]: 1 in x.values
Out[9]: True
```

**UPDATE**

I did some timings on my suggestions. It looks like `x.values` is the best way:

```
In [21]: x = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 100000, 1000))

In [22]: x.index = np.arange(900000, 900000 + 1000)

In [23]: x.tail()
Out[23]:
900995    88999
900996    13151
900997    25928
900998    36149
900999    97983
dtype: int64

In [24]: %timeit 36149 in set(x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 190 µs per loop

In [25]: %timeit 36149 in list(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 638 µs per loop

In [26]: %timeit 36149 in (x.values)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.86 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is may be helpful to think of the `pandas.Series` as being a bit like a dictionary, where the `index` values are equivalent to the `keys`. Compare:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1}
>>> 1 in d
False
>>> 'a' in d
True
```

with:

```
>>> s = pandas.Series([1], index=['a'])
>>> 1 in s
False
>>> 'a' in s
True
```

However, note that iterating over the series iterates over the `data`, not the `index`, so `list(s)` would give `[1]`, not `['a']`.

Indeed, per [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.html), the `index` values *"must be unique and hashable"*, so I'd guess there's a hashtable under there somewhere.

Comment: Strange, both my experience and [another pandas doc page][http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html] say that Pandas support non-unique indices

Comment: It looks like that particular piece of documentation is outdated. I posted a bug report.

Comment: @bgbg which piece; the one I linked or the one you linked?

Comment: Thinking of `index` values as `keys` is spot on. But then why wouldn't membership _also_ check keys? That's how every other data type operates. Series is the only one where `x in S for x in S` is going to be `False`.