# How to identify the occurrence of items in a list against another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file with a column of text which I have loaded. I would like to check the occurrence of country names in the loaded text. I have loaded the Wikipedia countries CSV file and I am using the following code to count the number of occurrences of country names in the loaded text.

My code is not working.

Here is my code:

    `text = pd.read_sql(select_string, con)
    text['tokenized_text'] = mail_text.apply(lambda col:nltk.word_tokenize(col['SomeText']), axis=1)
    country_codes = pd.read_csv('wikipedia-iso-country-codes.csv') 
    ccs = set(country_codes['English short name lower case'])
    count_occurrences=Counter(country for country in text['tokenized_text']if country in ccs)`

Comment: is `country_codes` the `dictionary`?

Comment: The current code you have has an indentation error - you should see to that, first.

Comment: No, the indentation was just the result of my cut and paste here

Comment: country_codes is the dataframe with the list of countries from wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

In your original code the line

```
dic[country]= dic[country]+1
```

should raise a `KeyError`, because the key is not yet present in the dictionary, when a country is met for the first time. Instead you should check if the key is present, and if not, initialize the value to 1.

On the other hand, it will not, because the check

```
if country in country_codes['English short name lower case']:
```

yields `False` for all values: a [`Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) object's `__contains__` works with [indices instead of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841768/python-pandas-why-does-the-in-operator-work-with-indices-and-not-with-the-d). You should for example check

```
if country in country_codes['English short name lower case'].values:
```

if your [list of values is short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319929/how-to-determine-whether-a-pandas-column-contains-a-particular-value).

For general counting tasks Python provides [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which acts a bit like a [`defaultdict(int)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), but with added benefits. It removes the need for manual checking of keys etc.

As you already have [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) objects, you could use the tools [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) provides:

```
In [12]: country_codes = pd.read_csv('wikipedia-iso-country-codes.csv')

In [13]: text = pd.DataFrame({'SomeText': """Finland , Finland , Finland
    ...: The country where I want to be
    ...: Pony trekking or camping or just watch T.V.
    ...: Finland , Finland , Finland
    ...: It's the country for me
    ...: 
    ...: You're so near to Russia
    ...: so far away from Japan
    ...: Quite a long way from Cairo
    ...: lots of miles from Vietnam
    ...: 
    ...: Finland , Finland , Finland
    ...: The country where I want to be
    ...: Eating breakfast or dinner
    ...: or snack lunch in the hall
    ...: Finland , Finland , Finland
    ...: Finland has it all
    ...: 
    ...: Read more: Monty Python - Finland Lyrics | MetroLyrics
    ...: """.split()})

In [14]: text[text['SomeText'].isin(
    ...:     country_codes['English short name lower case']
    ...: )]['SomeText'].value_counts().to_dict()
    ...:
Out[14]: {'Finland': 14, 'Japan': 1}
```

This finds the rows of `text` where the *SomeText* column's value is in the *English short name lower case* column of `country_codes`, counts unique values of *SomeText*, and converts to dictionary. The same with descriptive intermediate variables:

```
In [49]: where_sometext_isin_country_codes = text['SomeText'].isin(
    ...:     country_codes['English short name lower case'])

In [50]: filtered_text = text[where_sometext_isin_country_codes]

In [51]: value_counts = filtered_text['SomeText'].value_counts()

In [52]: value_counts.to_dict()
Out[52]: {'Finland': 14, 'Japan': 1}
```

The same with `Counter`:

```
In [23]: from collections import Counter

In [24]: dic = Counter()
    ...: ccs = set(country_codes['English short name lower case'])
    ...: for country in text['SomeText']:
    ...:     if country in ccs:
    ...:         dic[country] += 1
    ...: 

In [25]: dic
Out[25]: Counter({'Finland': 14, 'Japan': 1})
```

or simply:

```
In [30]: ccs = set(country_codes['English short name lower case'])

In [31]: Counter(country for country in text['SomeText'] if country in ccs)
Out[31]: Counter({'Finland': 14, 'Japan': 1})
```

Comment: So what happened to Russia and Vietnam? Are they no longer countries? I think that the source data could be better...

Comment: Russia is there, but it's not just "Russia", but the "Russian Federation". Vietnam on the other hand was not. OPs data and method could use some improvement.

Comment: Good point about Russia because it is never referred to as "Russian Federation" but just as "Russia" so maybe I need to find another source file for country codes?

Comment: Combining multiple data sources could help. Fuzzier matching as well, but that's getting besides the point a bit. In the end you probably have to accept some margin of error and go with it. A note about these kinds of tasks (check if list's elements exist in another): get used to using `set`s in the general case. A contains check is *O(1)* for sets, *O(n)* for sequences.

Comment: Do you mean convert the dataframe to a set and use intersection to identify the common elements? Would it work in this case?

Comment: There's no need in this case. Using intersection would not work for you anyway, as that'd just return what common elements 2 sets have, but without repetitions. What I meant was that if you'd have to work with plain lists etc., then it'd pay up to check for `item in a_set` instead of `item in a_list`.

Comment: As to why it is not necessary in this case, a recent enough pandas [does the converting to set for you](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L161).

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused by the solution provided above :(  I only have one column 'SomeText' - why is it being split()? and why are the identified elements not being added to a dictionary so that I can count them?

Comment: You did not provide a complete example with data, so I had to roll my own. It is just example data, don't mind it. The counting is done using pandas' tools (because you already have `DataFrame`s, and pandas is usually plenty fast), converting the final result to a dictionary.

Comment: So where is the resulting dictionary with elements and their number of occurrences? Is it in text['SomeText']?

Comment: At this point I must advice you to read or reread the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). It seems you have some difficulties with the very basic concepts of python.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown, it makes more sense to me now :)

Comment: Ok at the risk of sounding stupid, it is still not working. Using the 'set' solution provided: I have my set of country codes - CCS - and just to make sure i printed them out and they are all there, so the problem statement is:                                                                       Counter(country for country in text['SomeText'] if country in ccs)                                                                                                            It is not returning anything at all. I feel like I am missing something very obvious but I just cannot see what it is!

Comment: Do you assign the expression's result to a variable?

Comment: Yes, and it just gives an empty Counter:  Counter()

Comment: Hard to say this or that without the *actual data*. Perhaps you've tokenized your text in a way that has concatenated punctuation with words. Think `"Finland"` vs. `"Finland."`. The latter is not a match. You are really pushing the boundaries of a [minimal, **complete** and **verifiable** example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In other words: we cannot help you with incomplete information. What does your `DataFrame` *text* actually contain? And if you wish to add that information, *edit it in to the question itself, do not comment*.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!, I have amended my code and tokenized the extracted text (see amendment in question). The only problem is that this produces a list which gives a 'type error: Unhashable type'. Do I need to amend the loop because it is a list?