# Pandas: Why is 'in' broken Series?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When I run

```
the_id in attrs['ID']
2941264 in pd.Series([2941264,2941273,2941273,2941282]) # or this
```

I get `False`. But when I run

```
any(attrs['ID'].isin([the_id]))
```

I get `True`.

---

**How does a Pandas Series implement `in`?**

That is, **why** does Series have this unintuitive behaviour?

And how could different results be produced from it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe

Comment: `in` operator is generally implemented someplace. Where is that place?

Comment: @Wen: Bad dupe. The questioner has already found `isin`; they want to know what's up with `in`.

Comment: @user2357112 check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19960136/7964527

Comment: @Wen: That still doesn't explain what `thing in some_series` means.

Comment: @user2357112 if you think not a dup, you can reopen it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement 'in' and 'not in' for Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841768/python-pandas-why-does-the-in-operator-work-with-indices-and-not-with-the-d @user2357112 how about this one . :-)

Comment: @Wen: That's a much better dupe target.