# Why does Pandas Series `in` operate differently than every other data structure?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, series, membership

Most data structures utilize Python's `in` operator to *either* return `keys` *or* `values`. Pandas Series *mixes* these. My question is **why** are they mixed? Is there a functional purpose to this?

To be clear, I'm not asking how the mechanics work; that has been asked multiple times like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841768/python-pandas-why-does-the-in-operator-work-with-indices-and-not-with-the-d) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319929/how-to-determine-whether-a-pandas-column-contains-a-particular-value). I am asking why it was implemented in this (arguably counterintuitive) way.

I say counterintuitive because it results in behavior like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((3,3)),columns=['a','b','c'])
df.replace(1,'abc',inplace=True)

a = df['a']
print([x in a for x in a])

# This will print
# [False, False, False]
```

Every other data structure I can think of (including Pandas DataFrames) will return a list of `True` rather than `False` since membership (`x in a`) and iteration (`for x in a`) operate on the same item, *either* `keys` (like dictionaries) *or* `values` (like lists).

**TLDR:**  The Series object iterates over `values` and checks membership in `keys`. What's the reasoning behind this implementation?

---

P.S. For anyone landing here wondering **how** to iterate over the keys, simply use the `.values()' method on the Series object. It's most [efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319929/how-to-determine-whether-a-pandas-column-contains-a-particular-value).

Comment: I'm not sure SO is the right platform for this. This is an implementation detail that can be best answered by the pandas dev team.

Comment: @wkgrcdsam True, this is less of a usage question and more a general inquiry. Per their [Getting Help](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas#getting-help), I posted to the [PyData mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/pydata).