# non existing values in pandas dataframe return True if data frame doesn't converted into list first

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to understand why `5 in df['ids']` in code below return `True` since number 5 doesn't exist in the pandas dataframe.

```
In [82]: df = pd.DataFrame()

In [83]: df['ids'] = list(range(5)) + list(range(6,10))

In [84]: df
Out[84]: 
   ids
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    6
6    7
7    8
8    9

In [85]: 5 in df['ids']
Out[85]: True

In [86]: df[df['ids'] == 5]
Out[86]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ids]
Index: []

In [87]: 5 in list(df['ids'])
Out[87]: False
```

Comment: Doing `df['ids'][5]` may make it clear what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to understand that `pandas` objects care about the `.index` a lot. Because of the `.index`, `Series` can support a near-dictionary like behavior. From this perspective, just like checking `in` on a dictionary to check for key existence, it makes some sense that `in` on a `pandas` object checks for index existence.

So using the above, we can check:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9])
>>> s.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=8, step=1)

>>> 5 in s # implicitly check if 5 is in s.index
True
>>> 5 in s.index # explicitly check if 5 is in s.index
True

>>> 5 in s.values # explicitly check if 5 is in values
False
```

An alternative way to check if a value is in a `Series` you can use some boolean logic:

```py
>>> (5 == s).any()
False
```

Also see [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841768/python-pandas-why-does-the-in-operator-work-with-indices-and-not-with-the-d) as well.